# How to connect to mongoLab?

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack, mlab

I developed a simple MEAN stack CRUD app. I deployed my site to azure websites. In my localhost the app work fine. But I want to connect with mongoLab database. How can I connect it?

> This is the code for server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');


var db = mongojs('posts', ['posts']);
var bobyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bobyParser.json());//
app.get('/posts', function (req, res) {
console.log("I got the server request!")
db.posts.find(function (err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
    res.json(docs);
});
});



app.post('/posts', function (req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
//Insert - This is the first part of the CRUD
db.posts.insert(req.body, function (err, doc) {
    res.json(doc);
});
});


app.delete('/posts/:id', function (req, res) {
var id = req.params.id;
console.log(id);
db.posts.remove({ _id: mongojs.ObjectId(id) }, function (err, doc) {
    res.json(doc);
});
});


app.get('/posts/:id', function (req, res) {
var id = req.params.id;
console.log(id);
db.posts.findOne({ _id: mongojs.ObjectId(id) }, function (err, doc) {
    res.json(doc);
});
});

app.put('/posts/:id', function (req, res) {
var id = req.params.id;
console.log(req.body.name);
db.posts.findAndModify({
    query: { _id: mongojs.ObjectId(id) },
    update: { $set: { name: req.body.name, info: req.body.info, twitter:           req.body.twitter }},
    new: true
}, function (err, doc) {
    res.json(doc);
});
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Server running from port 3000");
```

How can I make the connection? I have the connection info what azure provides. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Can you look at the exact Exception error message? 
Try something like the following:

```
      try
        {
            smtp.Send(msg);
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Mensaje enviado correctamente');</script>");
            NullTextBox();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            Response.Write(string.Format("<script>alert('There is an error on connection to DB on microsoft azure:{0}');</script>", ex.ToString()));
            NullTextBox();
        }
```

[image]